# Pull markers from google map to make table of points on map

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, google-maps

Hey, does anyone know of a way to embed a Google map on a webpage write all the points on the map to a table on the page, where if they're clicked they will be displayed on the map?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this [google-maps-slider](http://css-tricks.com/google-maps-slider/)

The demo attaches an onMouseOver event but i am sure you can change that to onClick event.

Comment: That is basically what i was thinking about, but the way that works is to input the points with js and they'll be put on the map. I was looking to do it the other way around where instead of adding the points in js, the points from a map that i've made would be pulled and made into a table. But, thank you, I may just have to use this.

Comment: @Adam how are you creating the map?  are you using Google Map V3 API?

Comment: Currently the map is just embeded on the page that is querying a .kml file that is made in mymaps from google.

Comment: ah i see, i am not too sure about KML, but i know you have more control w/ the Google Map API

Comment: Yeah, i've come to realize that after a a 400 point map has been made :[ lol, i'll figure something out i hope. Thank you.